# Receiving a better salary offer while being on probation period

Tags: job-offer, probation

Let's say someone has just started a position that has a 3 month probation period in company A and still has 2 more months to go.

Then during this period, he/she happened to receive an offer from company B for a slightly higher salary.

What options does one have in this situation? Undoubtfully if all other conditions are equal the choice is simple: Just go to company B.

But what if working atmosphere/colleagues/etc is really good in company A and this aspect is uncertain about company B?

Comment: Your options are obviously to either take the new job or stay at your current one. We can't tell you which one to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If colleagues and atmosphere are exceptionally good on company A, then stay there, as this is something highly valuable. But normally, everyone and everything is nice on the beginning, if you are not an experienced professional, I'd advise against thinking you've landed at the Dream Workplace.

It is polite to always negotiate leaving you current job. If the difference is small, maybe it was even budgeted for your hiring process, so maybe you can stay at company A and get a better salary.

It also does not look bad on you if you leave after one month, your time at company A can surely be skipped on your CV if it's just one month.

But you should consider if you will indeed be a good fit for company B, as there will be a probation period there as well. You won't like to call to company A after being fired by company B and ask to come back (but do make this call nonetheless if this situation arrives).